# Fixing a gibberish filename in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

A friend has had trouble with a bunch of files that got renamed into gibberish. It lookes like this:

```
03-ñîáä-áøâì-ùîàì.mp3
```

when it should look like this:

```
03-סמבה-ברגל-שמאל.mp3
```

Now, the number of files is huge, so he asked if I could help with a python script. I started meddling, but it just won't budge. My assumption was that it was a CP-1255 (or `windows-1255`) presented as `utf-8`, so I tried:

```
fname.decode('utf-8').encode('windows-1255')
```

But I got the "can't encode characters" error. So I then tried switching them, and also tried `latin-1`, `windows-1252`, `cp862` and even `ISO-8859-8`. Nothing.

What should I do? Encoding has always been confusing for me. How do I deal with this?

I'm using python 2.7

Comment: I don't know how to help with the encoding, but I know that you can rename everything using `os.rename`

Comment: @Zizouz212 yeah I know that too, I'm not new to python

Comment: Have you tried it? Perhaps, if you were able to track down what was contained in the original file types, and renamed it to something, like numbers, and then rename them properly? Just an idea...

Comment: @Zizouz212 what? What file types? rename it to what exactly, and from where would I get the correctly encoded name? You have no idea what you're talking about...

Comment: Oh, my bad! Not file types, but the filenames... And the answer is here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it right, but the original encoding is `windows-1252`, not `utf-8`.

```
>>> print u'03-ñîáä-áøâì-ùîàì.mp3'.encode('cp1252').decode('cp1255')
03-סמבה-ברגל-שמאל.mp3
```

Comment: yeah, I tried that too. `mp3.decode('windows-1252').encode('utf-8')` results in `03-Ã±Ã®Ã¡Ã¤-Ã¡Ã¸Ã¢Ã¬-Ã¹Ã®Ã Ã¬.mp3.mp3`. It's a different gibberish, but still gibberish

Comment: @yuvi I made it work on my system, just trying to translate those results so I can edit it into the answer.

Comment: yes!!! actually we need to first decode it to utf-8 (I have it as a variable `fname`, so I can't just add a little nice `u''`). so we have:  `fname.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252').decode('cp1255')`. sheesh, what a headache. Thank you very much =]